# How to await a redis operation and catch an error in node.js?

Tags: node.js, express, error-handling, redis, async-await

What I want to do is (using express, redis modules):

```
router.post('/', async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        await client.set('key', value)
    } catch (err) {
        return next(err)
    }

    // should not be reached here if an error occured.
})
```

That is, I want to catch an error and return so that the rest of the code can't be executed. I tried `promisifyAll` using bluebird and `client.setAsync`, but catch didn't work.

---

[Edit]

I deliberately used wrong url for the connection. So, an error should be occurred.
If I pass a callback to `client.set` function as third parameter, I can see the error logs:

```
Error: Redis connection to asdf:6379 failed - connect ETIMEDOUT 216.157.88.27:6379
```

But, I can't `await` in this way.

Fortunately, I found `util.promisify` works well like this:

```
const client = redis.createClient()
const setAsync = util.promisify(redisClient.set.bind(redisClient))
...
    try {
        await setAsync('key', value)
    }
...
```

I don't know why bluebird didn't work. What I did is:

```
bluebird.promisifyAll(redis)
const client = redis.createClient()
...
    try {
        await client.setAsync('key', value)
    }
...
```

I referenced this document https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis#bluebird-promises

Comment: So you have an error, and is not caught? What is the error ?

Comment: `catch` doesn't work ? Or something is not so good in your code implementation...